# Bootstrap parallax tooltips and smooth scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, onload

I bought a template to use with Bootstrap because I am kind of in a hurry, and I want to edit it a bit so it does what I want to. I created a vertical menu with tooltips, but the tooltips aren't showing. When I use the exact same code in another file it works perfectly, so I think something is blocking it but I don't know why. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently [the way `localScroll` works](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) is that you need to specify the scroll properties on the element *containing* the links which will scroll to the designated location. Thus, you will want your HTML to change to something like this for your dot menu.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li id="dotLink1">
        <h1>First manned flights</h1>
        <a href="#top-section">View</a>
    </li>
    <li id="dotLink2">
        <h1>The frameless parachute</h1>
        <a href="#Section-1">View</a>
    </li>
    <li id="dotLink3">
        <h1>Over the English Channel</h1>
        <a id="dotLink3" href="#Section-2">View</a>
    </li>
    <li id="dotLink4">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <a id="dotLink4" href="#foot-sec">View</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you need to actually call the `localScroll` function on those container elements to tell them where the links should lead to like so:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#topnav, #dotLink1').localScroll(3000);
    jQuery('#startbtn, #dotLink2').localScroll(5000);
    jQuery('#dotLink3').localScroll(7000);
    jQuery('#dotLink4').localScroll(9000);
    //.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
    //xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
    //inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
    //outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport
    jQuery('#top-section').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    jQuery('#Section-1').parallax("70%", 0.3);
    jQuery('#Section-2').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    jQuery('#foot-sec').parallax("50%", 0.1);
});
</script>
```

Finally, you should remove your `onload` attribute from the `body` tag and put anything you want to run upon loading of the document inside the jQuery `jQuery(document).ready()` function. Since you've already got one going at the bottom, we'll put the code in there.

Instead of creating a new function, all you need to do is put the `window.location.hash` inside there. However, that alone won't make `localScroll` work. Luckily, `localScroll` has a function prepared for listening to the hash of the URL. This is `jQuery.localScroll.hash()`. Thus, you'll want to change the hash first and then call that like so:

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.location.hash = "Section-2";
    jQuery.localScroll.hash();
    jQuery('#topnav, #dotLink1').localScroll(3000);
    jQuery('#startbtn, #dotLink2').localScroll(5000);
    jQuery('#dotLink3').localScroll(7000);
    jQuery('#dotLink4').localScroll(9000);
    //.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
    //xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
    //inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
    //outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport
    jQuery('#top-section').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    jQuery('#Section-1').parallax("70%", 0.3);
    jQuery('#Section-2').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    jQuery('#foot-sec').parallax("50%", 0.1);
});
</script>
```

[Here is a JSBin to show it in action.](http://jsbin.com/ijIfEta/4/edit) (Don't 1:1 replace your code with the JSBin code since I had to make all the external JS/CSS/image links absolute links to resources on the web instead of keeping them relative links.)

And last but not least, to get the tooltips working, you want the `h1` elements to show when you're hovered over the buttons. One might think to put the `:hover` on the `h1`; however, that won't work since its current state is hidden. Thus your mouse can never hover over it. One might *then* think to put it on the `a` tag since that's the button; however, you won't be able to use selectors to target the `h1` from there since `a` comes after `h1` instead of before. Thus you should activate the `h1` when the mouse hovers over its parent element, which in this case is the `li`.

**CSS:**

```
nav#primary li:hover h1 {
    display:block;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

[New JSBin here.](http://jsbin.com/ijIfEta/6/edit)

Comment: No problem! One way you can do popup tooltips is to just use the `title` attribute on the `a` element. For example, instead of using the `h1`, you can have this: `<a href="#top-section" title="First manned flights">View</a>`. It's arguably not as stylish as if you had your own themed solution, but it works if it's not that important.

Comment: Actually, now I see your tooltip CSS. I'll see if I can solve that for you real quick.

Comment: Looking at this again, the number inside the `localScroll` function call is actually the time in milliseconds you want the scroll to take. I was slightly mistaken and thought they were positions on the page; thus I kept adding to them. It may feel better if all of them are the same, or just the first one is faster so that it scrolls to the top quickly.